Salesforce: Creating Quote PDF doesn't trigger ContentVersion insert trigger?
When creating a Quote PDF i want to react to this event by custom logic in a Salesforce Apex Trigger.
I created a trigger for it:
trigger QUOTEDOCTRIGGER on ContentVersion (after insert) {
    for (SObject cv : Trigger.new) {
        System.debug('********************************************' + String.valueOf(cv.Id) + '*************************************************');
    }
}

The created trigger isn't triggered and doesn't show up in the log.
When i do the same for ContentDocumentLink on the other hand it's being triggered.
trigger QUOTEDOCTRIGGER_CDL on ContentDocumentLink (after insert) {
    for (SObject cv : Trigger.new) {
            System.debug('******************************************** CDL: <' + String.valueOf(cv.Id) + '>*************************************************');
    }
}

Is this wanted behavior or a bug?
Please see also the Trailblazer Community thread regarding this topic which i opened.
Current Status
Currently, based on the observations I've made, I'm assuming this is a bug.
A Salesforce support ticket is necessary to be opened. Link will follow hopefully.

Are they created as Files (can you query them ok from contentversion afterwards) or as old school Attachments? Is the trigger deployed ok, activated? What kind of dml you see if you run this pdf creation with debug log enabled?

They are indeed created as queryable ContentVersion & ContentDocument objects.
The trigger is activated.
I'll provide the DML soon

So assuming I did enable debug log for DML actions correctly, I don't see any DML logs.
What I did is in the Developer Console to click in the Menu Bar on Debug -> Change Log Levels -> In the Column "DebugLevel Action" press on Add/Change -> Set log level of "DB" to "FINEST" and then typed "DML" into the filter field of the Execution Log as described here:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.code_dev_console_solving_problems_using_system_log.htm&type=5
Please correct me if I did anything wrong as I'm rather unsure about doing it right.

A standard debug log would suffice, Finest level is ok too. So. You had Dev console open (or turned debug logging on in the setup) and then generated the quote pdf, correct? And what does the debug log say? Does it have "dml_begin:insert:ContentVersion" for example? (Don't remember exact phrase, just search for dml_begin) Does it contain your trigger's name?

@eyescream Please find the redacted log on https://pastebin.com/69X1HDYk

I should add, that you see multiple triggers in the log file. But not the one above. The "Quote_FileCV_incoming on ContentVersion trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/Quote_FileCV_incoming" is as to be seen trigger "AfterUpdate".

That's a weird log, no sight of DML_BEGIN in the body. Doesn't show what actually created the record, straight to update (your trigger is after insert still)? it's possible it's created and not updated in the original transaction... I know it's an insulting question but you're sure you downloaded the right one? Maybe this is from some @future update and you needed file generated minimally earlier... There's even no code call that performs the insert, even a call to core SF functionality would be recorded somehow... Running out of ideas

Put something stupid in your after insert trigger like if(UserInfo.getLastName() == 'Panke'){assert.fail('pls throw');}. If you're still able to create docs and the trigger is deployed OK, active (you can see it in setup - object manager - content version - triggers)... Can you put an afterinsert trigger on ContentDocumentLink too and see if it fires?

Sorry for the delay.. so what I did was: Opening Developer Console -> Create a Quote PDF -> At the bottom look for logs -> Open the one with "Application: Browser" and "Operation: /aura" (which is the only one to be seen btw.)-> Enter in the filter field "DML". Yet there is no sight of DML to be seen other than the API limit stuff event "LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS".

I added System.Assert.fail('pls throw'); after the System.debug() call and made sure the trigger is deployed OK in the Object Manager. Still no sight of pls throw in the logs. I proceeded by creating the ContentDocumentLink Trigger after insert with basically the same code as the ContentVersion one which indeed let's the assertion fail.
I assume this is a bug in Apex?

I don't know man, maybe it's some hidden "feature" of SF that contentversion triggers don't run on quote pdfs. I saw few weird situations like that, in some obscure scenarios val rules and required fields are skipped... You'll be fine rewriting your logic to ContentDocumentLink trigger or need some guidance?

I'm assuming this is a bug as i stated in the description. I guess don't have any chance other than creating a support ticket @ Salesforce. I'm relying on this since I'm serializing triggers from a configuration made on my application. Therefore, unfortunately, ContentDocumentLink is not an option really. Or I have to have a special logic branch handling the creation of that one which i would really want to avoid. But thanks a lot for you help and the offered guidance.
